# Set operations validity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

First i define: $A= \{ 1, 2 \}$, $B = \{ \{ 1 \}, \{ 2 \} \}$ and $C = \{ \{ 1 \}, \{ 1, 2 \} \}$.
My question is: Which of the following statements are true: (i): $A=B$, (ii): $A \subseteq B$, (iii): $A \in C$?

Comment: Any idea/work done on it ?

Comment: I guess all of them are true because B should equal {1,2} and which makes statement (i) and (ii) already true. I guess C should equal {1,1,2}={1,2} so statement (iii) should be true too. What do you think?

Comment: $1$ is not $\{ 1 \}$.

Comment: Thats what i wanted to know! That makes statement (i) - (iii) false!

Comment: Yes.  Think of sets as "a bag containing...".  Is the the apple named $a$ the same as a bag containing that apple $a$ ? No, that is, $a \ne \{a\}$

Comment: But what does it mean when A is element of B. Would that mean B = {{1},{2},A} but then B would equal {{1},{2},1,2} which makes A a subset of B. Whats the difference of A beeing element of B or being a subset of B?

Comment: $A$ as given, is a set with two elements, 1, 2. B is a set with two SETS as is elements. Since B does not contain $A= \{1, 2\}, $ but only $\{1\}$, \{2\}\}$ as elements then $A$ cannot be either a subset, nor an element of B

Comment: A soldier is an *element* of a [platoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platoon), but a platton is a *subset* of a [company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Company_(military_unit)).

Answer (score 2):

$1\neq \{1\}$.  The first is a number, and the second is a set containing the number $1$.

$\{1, 2\}$ is a set, and it contains the element $1$ and element $2.$

$\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$ is a set containing two elements,and its elements, this time, are sets:$\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$

$C$ like $B$ contains two sets as elements. The first element is the set $\{1\}$, and the second element is the set $\{1, 2\}.$

For $iii)$ $A = \{1, 2\} \in C= \{\{1 \}, \{1, 2\} \}$